# Flush on pending bytes threshold

Tags: netty

I work in F5, a happy Netty adopter. We love Netty. :)

We are in the middle of the process of migrating some of our Netty 3 code to Netty 4.
One of the things that we would like to do in order to reduce CPU usage is applying some flush strategy on written message. For instance, summing outbound messages bytes, and flushing when reaching some threshold.

For Netty 3 we had a handler which did similar work (aggregating messages in a queue, and sending downstream sometime later). So every outbound message automatically was enforced to go through this handler. And as a handler we could set it after the encoding handler (outbound direction), so it sums up the resulted count of bytes before continue outbound.

Example for handler we could have in Netty 3 (from [BufferedWriteHandler javadoc](http://netty.io/3.8/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/queue/BufferedWriteHandler.html))

```
public class AutoFlusher extends BufferedWriteHandler {

 private final AtomicLong bufferSize = new AtomicLong();

 @Override
 public void writeRequested(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
     super.writeRequested(ctx, e);

     ChannelBuffer data = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
     int newBufferSize = bufferSize.addAndGet(data.readableBytes());

     // Flush the queue if it gets larger than 8KiB.
     if (newBufferSize > 8192) {
         flush();
         bufferSize.set(0);
     }
 }
}
```

In Netty 4 I would like to have:

```
public class AutoFlusher extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
// here, in netty 4, we have the aggregation of written messages 
// into queue inside core netty (ChannelOutboundBuffer), 
// so just extend simple adapter for summing written bytes 
// and flushing when crossing threshold

 private final AtomicLong bufferSize = new AtomicLong();

 @Override
 public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object e) {
     super.write(ctx, e);

     ByteBuf data = (ByteBuf) e;
     int newBufferSize = bufferSize.addAndGet(data.readableBytes());

     // Flush the queue if it gets larger than 8KiB.
     if (newBufferSize > 8192) {
         ctx.flush();
         bufferSize.set(0);
     }
 }
}
```

But in Netty 4 we have the new stricter thread model which does not allow us to do that - when the thread which calls `channel.write(...)` is not the channel's event loop thread.
That's because when such a thread calls `channel.write(...)`, it pushes its `WriteTask` in to the queue of the event loop thread, to run later.
`WriteTask` also implements `NonWakeupRunnable`, so the caller thread will not wake up the event loop thread (I guess for performances reasons). So if I used the same approach of having this handler - it's work for deciding whether to flush now or not will never be executed, or executed too late (it is waiting in the queue of the unawakened event loop thread).

The only way to do something similar I can think of is making sure (manually) that all calls to `write()` will also call to such "flushing manager" (not handler anymore). This will compute a decision whether to flush or not, and if yes - as a not-`NonWakeupRunnable` task it will wake up to event loop to execute all the pending `WriteTask`s + flush task really soon.

But then I seem to face the following issues:
1. How to enforce that ALL calls to `write()` also call that flushing manager. As said, it was obvious in Netty 3 as a handler (and the old thread model, which means caller thread of `channel.write()` will also operate the downstream pipeline work).
2. I have no access to the written buffer's bytes. Now that I have to call that flush manager outside of `write()`, meaning not as hook on the pipeline, and since the encoding will happen only in the future - I can't sum up the bytes when the `write()` returns - for deciding whether to flush or not.

So that could work, but only for counting pending written messages, not total bytes.
Unless you have better ideas?

Thanks! And keep up the good work!
Shay

Answer (score 2):

Basically you could just call `writeAndFlush(...)` always. That said with netty 4 you not need the handler anymore as we do this already for you. Just call `write(...)` and then `flush()` once you want to have it really written to the socket. This will also ensure we try to do a gathering write and so get you better performance.

Comment: Thanks Norman. The separation of `write()`-`flush()` is smart and I want to utilize it. Can I somehow cause netty to flush when, say, 10,240 bytes aggregated in `ChannelOutboundBuffer`? I know that I don't need `BufferedWriteHandler` for aggregating the written messages as was in netty 3 (because `ChannelOutboundBuffer` is in core netty), but I think I do need some handler for summing written bytes (`write(...)`) and calling flush on sum>10240. But as I explained above, it seems to me impossible by using a handler.

Comment: In fact it is possible... Just set the watermark via the ChannelOption or ChannelConfig to 10240 and then use override channelWritabilityChanged(...) in a ChannelInboundHandler and flush once the channel becomes non-writable.

Comment: Thanks Norman, but I think that it still might not work - if the caller thread of `channel.write(...)` is not the channel's event loop thread. As it will just push a `WriteTask` to the channel's event loop thread and return. It won't even wake it up to perform the `channelWritabilityChanged()`...  
Also, we already use the high-watermark feature to remove connection from pool, until it reaches again low watermark which returns it back in.

Comment: Sorry, seems I have a mistake in "It won't even wake it up to perform the channelWritabilityChanged()".  `channelWritabilityChanged(...)` will be set as task for the event loop, which will also cause the event loop to wake up. That's nice. Still, `channelWritabilityChanged(...)` is already taken by other feature of our system. And if I wanted to count messages in addition to bytes it won't be fired (do flush also on count of pending messages threshold).